# PHP, filling option box with multiple values

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, html-select

I currently have a page with some option boxes that each show a value from a database which pulls the corresponding record up on the next page.

I want to see if there is a way to fill one box with text for multiple values since they all apply to one single record anyway. Here is a screenshot of the current boxes:

[image]

And the code for one of those boxes:

```
<select name="workOrderPacket">

<?php

$sql = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT stageID,workOrderPacket FROM staging;");
while($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()){
    echo "<option value='{$row['stageID']}'>" . $row['workOrderPacket'] ."</option>";
}
?>  

</select>
```

Basically, I'd like for one option box to say "FebruaryZoneB1 | 170293 | 7006787"

but I don't know if I can actually put multiple values like that. I tried this:

```
echo "<option value='{$row['stageID']}'>" . $row['workOrderPacket'] .   $row['workOrderNum'] . "</option>";
```

But it doesn't load at all so I don't know if it just won't work or if it requires different syntax.

I wanted these boxes to load dependently off of one another but I can only use PHP, no ajax or jquery, and I'd rather just have one box that displays the records with more info.

Comment: try separating variables from string:

`echo "<option value='".$row['stageID']."'>" . $row['workOrderPacket'] ."</option>";`

Comment: check your php error log and see if there's any errors

Comment: Well, I don't have any errors because if I run the code as it is in the full block above it shows up fine. If I run the one that has 2 $row values, it also runs, but it still only shows the workOrderPacket value, not the workOrder Num value. I was hoping to be able to list multiple database values in one record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".chosen-select").chosen({
  no_results_text: "Oops, nothing found!"
})

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/harvesthq/chosen/gh-pages/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/harvesthq/chosen/gh-pages/chosen.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<form action="http://httpbin.org/post" method="post">
  <select data-placeholder="Begin typing a name to filter..." multiple class="chosen-select" name="workOrderPacket">

    <option value=""></option>
    <?php
        $sql = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT stageID,workOrderPacket FROM staging;");
        while($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()){
            echo "<option value='{$row['stageID']}'>".$row['workOrderPacket'] ."</option>";
        }
    ?>  
  </select>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Try this, hope this will fulfill your requirement. note, this is not tested yet. you should also look at this [Pen](https://codepen.io/elmahdim/pen/hlmri)